# Headers are not shown in exported excel file from primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, data-export

I have a datatable like this. But it would not export the headers to excel :

```
<h:form id="formOptionList">
<p:dataTable id="OptionTable"
             var="Options"
             widgetVar="OptionTable"
             value="#{managedBean.options}"
             filteredValue="#{managedBean.filteredOptions}"
             emptyMessage="No  Options found."
             rendered="#{managedBean.userPreferences.showTable}"
             paginator="true"
             rows="10"
             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="20,50,100"
             >

<p:column id="id" headerText="ID" filterBy="id" filterMatchMode="exact" width="12%" rendered="#{managedBean.userPreferences.showID}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{options.optionID}" />
</p:column>
....
....

</p:dataTable>

<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <p:panel header="Export All Data">
        <h:commandLink>
            <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/menuicons/options.png" />
            <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="OptionTable" fileName="Options" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGrid>

 </h:form>
```

So I changed it to

```
 <p:column id="id" filterBy="id" filterMatchMode="exact" width="12%" rendered="#{managedBean.userPreferences.showID}" >
    <f:facet name="header>">
        <h:outputText value="Option ID"/>
   </f:facet>
   <h:outputText value="#{Options.OptionID}" /> 
</p:column>
```

And I still don't see the headers in the excel file. Any ideas ?

Headers are not shown in exported excel file from primefaces datatable

Comment: Are you able to see `atleast` your data in exported `ExCEL` file?

Comment: Yes I am able to export the data. I just don't see headers in the excel sheet.

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but the main problem here is that there's a typo in `<f:facet name="header>">`.

Comment: The typo is probably just a typo.  If you test DataExporter on [the PrimeFaces Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml), the behavior is the same - no headers are generated in the output, whether XLS or PDF or other.  Newer versions of PrimeFaces have an `exportHeader` option defaulting to true, but this does not appear to modify the behavior.  As a workaround, you might be able to use a `postProcessor` to manually insert the headers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<p:column id="id" filterBy="#{Options.OptionID}" filterMatchMode="exact" width="12%" rendered="#{managedBean.userPreferences.showID}" >
    <f:facet name="header>">
        <h:outputText value="Option ID"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{Options.OptionID}" /> 
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

You put a `<h:outputText value= ""/>` after your `</f:facet>` ?

```
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Your Column Name" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="Your value" />
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a new column with display none, from the existing column just put an exporter false

```
<p:column id="id" filterBy="# Options.OptionID}"filterMatchMode="exact" width="12%" rendered="#anagedBean.userPreferences.showID}"exporter="false">
        <f:facet name="header>">
                    <h:outputText value="Option ID" />
        </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{Options.OptionID}" />
</p:column>
```

Add new column with display none and remove all sorting,filtering and rendering

```
<p:column exporter="true" style="display:none;">
    <f:facet name="header>">
        <h:outputText value="Option ID"/>
   </f:facet>
   <h:outputText value="#{Options.OptionID}" /> 
  </p:column>
```

This works perfectly.